# Nesting Flux Data

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

In my app, I make two ajax calls to for one piece of data. First I make a call to get a list of `ecommerceIntegrations`. Once I have those, I can then grab each of their respective `orders`.

My current code looks something like this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    EcommerceIntegrationStore.addChangeListener(this._onIntegrationStoreChange);
    OrderStore.addChangeListener(this._onOrderStoreChange);

    WebshipEcommerceIntegrationActionCreators.getEcommerceIntegrations();
},

_onIntegrationStoreChange: function() {
    var ecommerceIntegrations = EcommerceIntegrationStore.getEcommerceIntegrations();
    this.setState({ecommerceIntegrations: ecommerceIntegrations});
    ecommerceIntegrations.forEach(function(integration) {
        WebshipOrderActionCreators.getPendingOrdersOfIntegration(integration.id);
    });
},

_onOrderStoreChange: function() {
    this.setState({
        pendingOrders: OrderStore.getAllPendingOrders(), 
        pendingOrdersByIntegration: OrderStore.getPendingOrdersByIntegration()
    });
}
```

I'm trying to follow Facebook's Flux pattern, and I'm pretty sure this doesn't follow it. I saw some other SO posts about nesting data with Flux, but I still don't understand. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything here looks good except this:

```
ecommerceIntegrations.forEach(function(integration) {
    WebshipOrderActionCreators.getPendingOrdersOfIntegration(integration.id);
});
```

Instead of trying to fire off an action in response to another action (or worse yet, an action for every item in `ecommerceIntegrations`), back up and respond to the original action.  If you don't yet have a complete set of data, and you need to make two calls to the server, wait to fire the action until you have all the data you need to make a complete update to the system.  Fire off the second call in the XHR success handler, not in the view component.  This way your XHR calls are independent of the dispatch cycle and you have moved application logic out of the view and into an area where it's more appropriately encapsulated.

If you really want to update the app after the first call, then you can dispatch an action in the XHR success handler before making the second call.

Ideally, you would handle all of this in a single call, but I understand that sometimes that's not possible if the web API is not under your control.

In a Flux app, one should not think of Actions as being things that can be chained together as a strict sequence of events.  They should live independently of each other, and if you have the impulse to chain them, you probably need to back up and redesign how the app is responding to the original action.